# MenuItem command called when clicking IsCheckable checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

My XAML:

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding ShowRequestsCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding ShowUrgentEvaluationRequestNotification, Source={x:Static Properties:Settings.Default}, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <MenuItem.Header>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <Border Background="Red" CornerRadius="5" Padding="3,1,3,1" Margin="1,1,5,1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="18"></Border>
             <TextBlock>Beställningshanteraren</TextBlock>
         </StackPanel>
    </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

So it's a MenuItem with some stuff in the header, it is checkable, and that value is supposed to have some functionality elsewhere, it also has a command.

My problem is that when you click the checkbox, the command is called, which is not my intention, and it seems wrong for any situation honestly. You should be able to click the checkbox without activating whatever the MenuItem is supposed do do. I get the same result if I add a click event on the menuitem instead.

Why does WPF work like this? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Why are you attaching a command to the MenuItem if you don't want it to execute a command? [Edit:] Oh hey I just noticed how old this is. You probably don't care anymore.